# Genymotion how to debug with Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools, genymotion

We're using Genymotion to test/debug a WebView based Android Application. 
The device show up in Chrome Dev Tools via Inspect Device, but with no inspection ability.
We made different attempts, with/whitout ADB, with/whitout Android Studio but with no luck.
What's wrong/missing ?

Answer (score 71):

See [the official docs on enabling debugging on Android](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging)

1. Start up your Virtual Device and, **inside the virtual device**, enable "USB debugging" by going to **Settings** > **Developer Options** > **USB Debugging**.  If you get a prompt that says "always allow USB debugging", press "OK".  If you don't see the option for **Developer Options**, first goto **Settings > About Phone/Tablet**, find **Build Number**, and tap it about 10 times.  Go up one menu and find the Developer Options menu now enabled above the About menu options.
2. Go to Chrome on your Host OS. type `chrome://inspect` in the url and press enter.
3. Check the box at the top that says "Discover USB Devices".  There should now be a list of virtual devices currently available to Chrome.  Find the device you want to debug and click the `inspect` link.
4. A new Chrome Developer Tools window should open up containing the code for the page you're currently viewing in your browser, and should show the "Emulation" tab at the bottom with information about your device specs.

If you are not able to get this working then check the following items:

- Check port forwarding.
- Proxy settings.
- USB driver installation.

Comment: didn't found any option to turn on `usb debugging` in genymotion

Comment: usb debugging will be present in Settings -> Developer Options.
If developer options is not present then go to Settings -> About Phone and tap Build number 10 times, developer options will be enabled

Comment: @coding_idiot I was confused too. I believe user3048095 is referring to the Android Device settings, not Genymotion configuration. So Device > Settings (app) > About Phone *click on build number 10x* (this actually works) then go back one level and you'll see *Developer Options*

Comment: Hi Aubricus, U r rt. it is android device settings not genymotion configuration.

Comment: [Here are the offical docs](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) for reference.

Comment: @HarshaVardhan: What do you mean with "U r rt."?

Comment: @phresnel, "U r rt." means "You're right". The information provided by Aubricus is right

Comment: I turned on usb debugging, and I see my emulator listed on about:/inspect, but there is no `inspect` link like you said.

Comment: I too see emulator listed but no inspect link. I'm running Android 4.2.2 in my genymotion vm.

Comment: I'm also running into the same issue. I see the device in Chrome, but no `inspect` button. Just a guess, but maybe it's because we're not using Chrome on the device, but the default non-Chrome browser.

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900032/chome-dev-tools-and-genymotion-android-emulator

Comment: The "inspect" button links you to an instance of Chrome running in the device. If there is no instance of Chrome running in the device, you'll not see an "inspect" button.

Comment: I find the lack of the inspect button as well and I have seen this work with a physical connected device so I know what I should see and how this works.

Comment: The reason all of you're not getting an "inspect" button (even after doing all specified in the answer above) is probably because you are running Android versions below 4.4 (KitKat). As the docs says: "To begin remote debugging, you need ... For app debugging: Android 4.4+ ..."

Comment: Like other mentioned, but it may be not clear, you need to have the webview started or in other words, you need to have your application started. If your custom app contains a webview (not talking about the Chrome application!), the "inspect" link will appear automatically.

Comment: Pictures are worth a thousand words.... There are many systems here. Host Geny Chrom your app etc... Try to be precise with your wording.