# Chrome Dev Tools and Genymotion Android Emulator

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools, genymotion

Reference: [Genymotion how to debug with Chrome Dev Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21627328/genymotion-how-to-debug-with-chrome-dev-tools)

I'm also trying to get chrome developer tools to work with a genymotion emulator. However, when I follow all of the steps recommended (including at the above link), I don't get the "inspect" link. See: http://neu14.com/demos/screenshot.png

Note:  I found out that the default browser on the android devices, at least on most of the prior os versions is not Chrome. Finding an apk to download for Chrome android compatible versions, without an actual google play account, is quite challenging?

Comment: I also get this same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took me ages to get the remote debugging working on Genymotion as I couldn't install Chrome on it without the Google play store which isn't installed by default.

Finally found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrlaofRQyG0) so thought I'd share. It explains how to install [this virtual device](https://docs.google.com/a/songdrop.com/uc?id=0B_7IFWOq37FaUTVUc3FzX01Palk&export=download) which has the play store ready installed. Once that was set up and I could install Chrome and set up remote debugging. 
Won't work with the default android browser though as you said, but its a step forward!

Hope that helps

Comment: The video that you linked does provide a way to run a virtual environment and then install the Chrome browser. But how can I use the Chrome browser on a HTC One XL emulator since it is not install on that virtual environment.

Comment: chrome is now my default browser but still i can't see that in my list ( other websites which i open in chrome on my tablet are visible )

Answer (score 4):

I know my answer is little late, but I thought it may be helpful for someone

1) In the device, go to dev settings/ dev tools and enable USB debugging.
2) Start your app on genymotion (for instance if you are using ionic framework, then launch the app using "ionic run android"
3)Go to you chrome and try running "chrome://inspect"

4) Also , please ensure that you have android 4.4 or above version. Else it wont work. I spent quite a lot of time because i was using android 4.3 version.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I found it far simpler to use a product like Ghostlab (https://www.vanamco.com/ghostlab/) (paid product).

It will let you connect to the site running on your host machine, from the Genymotion emulator. You can then launch chrome dev tools from your host machine.