# Can't get Chrome Dev Tools to work with Genymotion

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools, genymotion

I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21627328/genymotion-how-to-debug-with-chrome-dev-tools)'s answer to get my debugger working but for some reasons I stuck at step 3:

> Check the box at the top that says "Discover USB Devices". There should now be a list of virtual devices currently available to Chrome. Find the device you want to debug and click the inspect link.

My problem is there is **no** "inspect link". The app I want to debug is running and I enabled *USB Debugging*

Answer (score 0):

**There is no application to debug. You need to install
[mobile Chrome Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome) first.**

- [How to install Google Play Services in a Genymotion VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su).

Also you need at least Desktop Chrome 42 to make inspect accessible.